# Microsoft Graph API BETA - Reports returning userPrincipalName encrypted/hashed

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When calling one of reports endpoints, eg https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json

The userPrincipalName returned looks something like  91AFD71ACEEFDD92B5B0A041F0E2FDA6 for our tenant but I see the expected email in our test tenant.

I didnt see anything in the documentation on additional permissions required or other potential security settings. How do I get the actual UPN when calling the reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For others that may run into this in the future:

An Office 365 administrator must disable the setting "Display anonymous identifiers" under Settings->Reports.

See [MS Support Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090039/reports-show-anonymous-instead-of-actual-user-names-in-office-365)

Comment: It was really a great help

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have tried this with the endpoint`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json`, however i get the response like the below

`{
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.teamsUserActivityUserDetail",
            "reportRefreshDate": "2018-11-27",
            "userPrincipalName": "XX@domain.onmicrosoft.com",
            "lastActivityDate": null,
            "isDeleted": false,
            "deletedDate": null,
            "assignedProducts": [
                "OFFICE 365 ENTERPRISE E3 DEVELOPER"
            ],
            "teamChatMessageCount": 0,
            "privateChatMessageCount": 0,
            "callCount": 0,
            "meetingCount": 0,
            "hasOtherAction": false,
            "reportPeriod": "7"
        },`

I have read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/plan-connect-userprincipalname), If you set enable Alternate login ID with Azure AD, it may get the response as you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the info but not sure it helps. If I run `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users` I get the expected UPN, only reports is not showing the upn correctly