# Unknow value in field UserPrincipalName. Getonedriveactivityuserdetail graph API

Tags: api, graph, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When accessing the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getOneDriveActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json graph API from a specific tenant, the value of the userPrincipalName field in response is an unknown string. Ex:  "userPrincipalName ":  "BE4EFE9E83863382382492509E8BD85E ". The correct response value for this field should be the user's e-mail

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlL79.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506858/microsoft-graph-api-beta-reports-returning-userprincipalname-encrypted-hashed),so we can refer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Your Office 365 settings is set to display anonymous identifiers. Have your Office 365 Administrator disable the setting. See [MS Support Document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4090039/reports-show-anonymous-instead-of-actual-user-names-in-office-365)