# Pulling Microsoft Teams user activity data through Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph Explorer to run a query that will allow me to pull data regarding Microsoft Teams usage for my organisation. Having read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0), I firstly gained the appropriate [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/reportroot-authorization) that should allow me to do this from our IT department. By looking at the Azure portal, I can see that I have the Reports Reader role so the permissions should not be an issue.

I want to be able to pull the data as a csv file, and the given query example within the documentation should allow me to do this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
```

However, when running this query the response returns nothing - not even an error message.

I've been looking through other posts around Microsoft Graph with Microsoft Teams data, and in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506858/microsoft-graph-api-beta-reports-returning-userprincipalname-encrypted-hashed) older post they noted using this query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json
```

I decided to try this query, and to my surprise in the response preview the data had been returned this time (albeit it is json rather than csv).

Does anyone know why the second query worked, but the first one which was pulled straight from the documentation did not? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If it doesnt return nothing, then its telling it doesnt have any usage records. Check your admin portal > reports and see if it contains any data or not. If not, i would say Graph API gets/returns the same data. In case if you see any differences between the two then i would suggest opening support ticket with Microsoft, so that they can help.

Comment: I would have thought that were the case, but if I go into the Microsoft 365 Admin Centre and navigate to the usage reports, there are full reports available containing many many records regarding MS Teams usage, as well usage for other Microsoft services.

And as I also said above, the second query returned the usage data from the reports in json format - so I know that data exists.

Comment: Cool. If the data exists in Admin centre, report the issue with MS support and they can investigate at their end why the API returns differently.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered the same thing, you need to convert the results of the query fm csv. I created a variable from the output and converted it fm csv. I used..

$webrequestoutput = "your get http request"

$UserDetailResults = ConvertFrom-Csv -inputobject $

Then either export to CSV or just view the variable